# JQuery, include a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been trying this for 3 days but couldn't find a solution yet. I need to load a php page with javascript. I'm using the code bellow however changing the page while the function is still working slows the page down.

```
$.post("connect.php?refresh_steamdata=true",{
},
function(data)
{
    alert("loaded!");
});
```

Comment: I can't tell how you're trying to concatenate your PHP and JavaScript strings.

Comment: you need to explain your question better, you want to include a php file on client's machine? or when php is compiling a page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to include a php file with jquery"? Are you trying to load a php file into another page using jQuery? If so you can use AJAX. And that would be a GET request not POST.

Comment: what you've written there is probably the best you're going to do but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: it does work but, the function won't stop if I head to another page that has the same javascript function. so the new page loads slower.

Answer (score 0):

load() is a simplified version of Post that replaces the contents of an element with the response from the server.

".load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data."

$.post() will get you the result you are looking for but it does so Asynchronously.  This means that if you plan to do something with the response you get back from the server you need to do it inside of the success function

```
$.post("<? echo $js_url."?refresh_steamdata=true"; ?>",{},function(data){
    alert("loaded!");
    // do something with data HERE
});

// not here since this will run before the data is returned
```

Comment: i wanna use the .load too. Actually, I don't want to do anything with results. I want to load a php that sets the user info into the sessions.

Comment: like i said above, load is actually just a simplified version of post that specifically loads the results from the server into an element.  $('#mydiv').load('myphp.php');  will put the values returned from myphp.php INTO #mydiv as HTML.  This is not what you are trying to do

Comment: Actually `.load()` is GET by default unless data is provided as an object. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: "This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data."

Comment: $.load("<? echo $js_url."?refresh_steamdata=true"; ?>", function() {
  alert("Steam Data"); }); now it won't ever alert anything.

Comment: My point is in your answer you state "load() is a simplified version of Post". When in fact load() is a GET request by default. Not a POST request.` $.get(url, data, success)` is also a GET request.